# JSF2 internationalization example

Tags: jsf-2

Taking as a start point the JSF2 internationalization example of this link:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/

I want this example to display the language of the combos in the actual language selected.

Could somebody point me how this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of setting the proper labels in the static variable `countries`:

```
static {
    countries = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
    countries.put("English", Locale.ENGLISH); //label, value
    countries.put("Deutsch", Locale.GERMAN);
    countries.put("Français", Locale.FRENCH);
    // ... fill in with additional languages/locales as needed
}
```

You can get a bigger list of language names in their original language here: http://www.omniglot.com/language/names.htm

**UPDATE:** According to OP's comment, he needs the language names translated to every language. For that, one could come up with a solution simply making a map of language maps (*that's quite a few maps*), like this:

```
// set a default value for localeCode
private String localeCode = Locale.ENGLISH.toString();
// ...
static {
    countries = new LinkedHashMap<Object, <String,Object>>();
    englishCountries = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
    englishCountries.put("English", Locale.ENGLISH); //label, value
    englishCountries.put("German", Locale.GERMAN);
    englishCountries.put("French", Locale.FRENCH);
    countries.put(Locale.ENGLISH, englishCountries);
    germanCountries = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
    germanCountries.put("Englisch", Locale.ENGLISH);
    germanCountries.put("Deutsch", Locale.GERMAN);
    germanCountries.put("Französisch", Locale.FRENCH);
    countries.put(Locale.GERMAN, germanCountries);
    frenchCountries = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
    frenchCountries.put("Anglais", Locale.ENGLISH);
    frenchCountries.put("Allemand", Locale.GERMAN);
    frenchCountries.put("Français", Locale.FRENCH);
    countries.put(Locale.FRENCH, frenchCountries);
    // ... fill in with additional languages/locales as needed
}

public Map<Object, <String,Object>> getCountriesInMap() {
    return countries;
}

// adapted value change listener from original:
public void countryLocaleCodeChanged(ValueChangeEvent e){
    String newLocaleValue = e.getNewValue().toString(); 
    //loop country map to compare the locale code
    for (Object key : countries.keySet()) {
        if (key.toString().equals(newLocaleValue)) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
                .setLocale((Locale) key);
        }
    }
}
```

and then you would choose the proper map to be used for the selectItems, with something like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{language.localeCode}" onchange="submit()"
    valueChangeListener="#{language.countryLocaleCodeChanged}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{language.countriesInMap[language.localeCode]}" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

<sub>**Note:** Don't forget to set a default value for `language.localeCode`, or the dropdown won't show any options</sub>

Please note, though, that this is probably **NOT** a good idea for usability, since a user who chooses a foreign language by mistake may have a hard time to get back to a known language for her (that's why it's a good practice to make the lists have the language names in each own language).

Comment: Maybe I don't express myself right. I want the selectOneMenu to show the label of the language accordingly to how it is named in the locale selected.
For example, if the actual locale is en_EN, the German language should be displayed as 'German', and if the actual locale is de_DE, the German language should be displayed as 'Deutch'. Thanks

Comment: oh, alright! hmm... you're gonna need a few more maps for that. let me come up with a new solution for that...

Comment: I've updated my answer with the changed you would need to do to use the translated language names. Please note also my comment about the usability issues this approach could raise.

Comment: Your usability note has opened my eyes. I am going to forget my originally desired approach and left things as they are. Thanks!